# query a URL every H hours for changes in the results?

Tags: rss, cron, url

How can I query a specific URL (mostly html and js) every H hours for changes in html content, which is mostly an html table with some header, and have the results fed to an RSS? This URL in question doesn't have an RSS feed.

Comment: How do you define change?

Comment: What are your programming skills like? In the past I've written a Java application that opens a HTTP connection to a given URL, it's pretty simple.